# Is it possible to have multiple ion-side-menu directives in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

What I try to do is have two different set of ion-side-menu, but it seems the first one always got overwritten by the second declared ion-side-menu directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have have one side menu per side.  for exemple, one  `<ion-side-menu side="left">` and one `<ion-side-menu side="right">`

if you need your sidemenu to be changed depending on a context value, then use the power of angularJS to declare some `ng-if="context1"` or `ng-if="!context1"` to present different sidemenu templates